# Jquery data table pagination is not showing

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm using the latest version of jquery data table in my project, but the pagination is not showing in my table.

The css is ok and I'm using jquery 1.7.

Jquery code:

```
$("#accessControlTable").dataTable({
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "iDisplayStart": 1,
            "bSort": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sZeroRecords": "   ",
                "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst": "First",
                    "sPrevious": "Previous",
                    "sNext": "Next",
                    "sLast": "Last"
                }
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like many of the features of DataTables don't work with JQuery 1.7.  See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsx7E/2/) to switch between JQuery 1.7 and 1.8 easily.  Everything works as expected in 1.8 and above but not in any previous versions.  Is upgrading your version of JQuery possible?

I tested using the basic initialization.

HTML:

```
<table id='accessControlTable'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th>col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#accessControlTable").dataTable();
```

Comment: You're right. The jquery version was out of date. When I upgraded the jquery version to 1.10.2, the problem was solved. Thanks